Django Test Setup Error: django_content_type Table Issue with MySQL Backend
I'm encountering an issue while setting up Django tests with a MySQL backend. The error occurs during the test database setup phase, specifically related to the django_content_type table. Here are the details:
Environment:

Django Version: 5.0.7

MySQL Version: 8.0.37

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04

Python Version: 3.11.12


Error:
When I run python manage.py test --settings=bms.settings_test (bms is my project name), I receive the following error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'django_content_type'")
[settings_test.py]
from .settings import *
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "usersdb",
        "USER": "test_user",
        "PASSWORD": "test_password", 
        "HOST": "10.128.0.9", # private ip add of database server
         "PORT": "3306",
    },
}

[test_users.py]
from django.test import TestCase
from users.models import Users

class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    databases = {'default', 'usersdb'}

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Setup non-modifiable test data
        cls.user = Users.objects.create_user(
            username='testuser',
            email='testuser@example.com',
            password='secret'
        )

    def test_user_creation(self):
        user = Users.objects.get(username='testuser')
        self.assertEqual(user.email, 'testuser@example.com')
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password('secret'))

    def test_user_string_representation(self):
        user = Users.objects.get(username='testuser')
        self.assertEqual(str(user), user.username)

Steps Taken:

Permissions: Confirmed that the test_user has all necessary privileges, including CREATE, ALTER, and DROP.

Database Setup: Dropped and recreated the test database manually to ensure a clean slate.

SQL Mode: Adjusted SQL mode settings to avoid strict mode issues (SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';).

Migrations: All migrations are applied successfully as verified with python manage.py showmigrations --settings=bms.settings_test.
Show migrations includes this as well:

contenttypes
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_remove_content_type_name


Database Configuration: Double-checked settings_test.py to ensure proper configuration, including the correct database name and user credentials.


Additional Information:
The django_content_type table does not seem to be created or accessed properly during the test setup.
The error does not occur in the development environment, only during testing.
Expecting: I am expecting that when I run python manage.py test --settings=bms.settings_test, it should create all required database setups and run tests. But it's not happening. It only creates database "test_usersdb" and creates tables mentioned below, and then it gives that above mentioned error:
Tables_in_test_usersdb:

auth_group

auth_group_permissions

auth_permission

django_migrations


Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with the django_content_type table not being created or accessible during Django test setups with a MySQL backend? What additional steps can I take to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your help!

Mysql typically generates this error when the refeneced (parent) table of a foreign key does not exist. Please confirm that it does exist.
